# How to extract the witness from exists in Coq in function notation/without destructing?

Tags: coq, witness

Assuming I have some definition with a forall and an exists like so:

```
Definition fooable A B P := forall a : A, exists b : B, P a b.
```

Then on an intuitive level, I can for each `(a : A)` find a `(b : B)` such that `(P a b)` holds, so it stands to reason that I can build a function that generates the `b` from the `a`. As Coq is constructive, there has to be a witness for the `b` if I have evidence for `fooable`, so I am trying to define this function:

```
Definition fooify A B P (H : fooable A B P) : A -> B.
```

Using `fun a => H a` to get rid of the `forall` is easy enough, but how can I extract the witness from the `exists` here? I've also tried writing it as a proof and `destruct`ing the `exists`, but as the goal is a `Type`, not a `Prop`, `destruct` errors.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In mathematics there are *two* kinds of existence:

1. The **concrete** or **informative existence** happens when we show that something exists by constructing a specific instance, which is then available.
2. The **abstract** or **non-informative existence** happens when we know that something exists by indirect means, or because the constucted witness has been hidden away from us by some mechanism.

An example that students come accross is this:

> **Theorem:** *There is a non-computable function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.*

*Abstract existence proof:* there are uncountably many function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ but only countably many Turing machines, therefore some functions must be non-computable. $\Box$

*Concrete existence proof:* we claim that the function $h : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by

$$
h(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $n$-th Turing machine halts on input $n$},\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
is not computable. (Insert here the standard proof that $h$ is not-computable.) $\Box$

I hope this conveys the idea clearly enough. First-order logic only expresses the abstract existence. Martin-Löf type theory only expresses the concrete existence.

Coq can express *both* kinds of existence. The abstract one is `exists` and the concrete one is `sig`. So if you want to actually extract witnesses, then you should be using `sig`, not `exists`.

In Coq `sig (fun (x : A) => P x)` is written in the more readable notation `{x : A | P x}`. Here is the extraction function you asked for:

```
Definition extract {A B : Type} (P : A -> B -> Prop) :
  (forall a, { b : B | P a b }) -> { f : A -> B | forall a, P a (f a) }
:=
  fun g => exist (fun f => forall a, P a (f a)) (fun a => proj1_sig (g a)) (fun a => proj2_sig (g a)).
```

It is possible to do violence to Coq and extract functions from the wrong existence by postulating various choice principles (as in [`Coq.Logic.ChoiceFacts`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.ChoiceFacts.html)), but it's just better to use the correct form of existence.

P.S. The difference between informative and non-informative facts extends to all of logic and is not specific to existence. We may distinguish between *informative* facts, where knowing a fact also gives us the ability to inspect the *reason* for knowing it, and the *non-informative* facts, where we simply know a fact, but have no access to any reason as to why the fact holds. In Coq the non-informative facts are in `Prop`, whereas the informative ones are in `Type`.

Comment: Fascinating. I knew of that difference in mathematics, but I thought exists was concrete. That explains everything, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Extracting a function from a forall/exists statement is a choice principle not derivable in Coq (at least not without axioms). More precisely, this extraction could be derived out of `FunctionalChoice_on` (to get the existence of a function out of the forall/exists) and `ConstructiveIndefiniteDescription_on` (to actually extract a function witnessing the existential) from the module [Coq.Logic.ChoiceFacts](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.ChoiceFacts.html) in the "standard" library. That file also discuss in length the subtle relationship between many different types of choice axioms.

Comment: Alternatively, you could replace the propositional existential (`ex`) with one in Type (`sig`), from which you can extract a function without any axiom.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned extracting a value from an existential is a choice principle.

You can however extract a Prop or type squashed to Prop.

The usual impredicative encoding of squashing is

```
Definition squash (A: Type): Prop := forall B: Prop, (A -> B) -> B.
```

But this can be a little awkward

```
Variant squash (A: Type): Prop :=
| squash_intro: A -> squash A.
```

Is also awkward.

Writing the function

```
Definition proj_ex1 {A} {P: A -> _}: (exists x: A, P x) -> squash A.
```

Is then pretty simple.

Coq is pretty bare bones in terms of standard library and as far as I know doesn't offer a version of `squash` or ergonomic tools for working with it. (Edit: use `inhabited`.) `squash` is straightforwardly a monad and an applicative functor.

I generally find it easier to rework things to be in Set or Type instead of working around Prop though myself.

Comment: Coq does have a `squash`. It is [`Inductive inhabited (A : Type) : Prop := inhabits : A -> inhabited A.`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Logic.html#inhabited), and should be imported by default.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on kyo dralliam's answer, here is how you would actually extract witnesses from `exists` in Coq. Note that, in the words of Andrej Bauer, you have to "do violence to Coq" in order to perform what you asked for. In this case the violence amounts to introducing the `constructive_indefinite_description` axiom, which is a form of choice.

```
From Coq Require Import IndefiniteDescription.

Definition fooable A B P := forall a : A, exists b : B, P a b.

Definition fooify A B P (H : fooable A B P) : A -> B.
Proof.
  intros a.
  destruct (constructive_indefinite_description _ (H a)) as [b Pab].
  exact b.
Defined.

Goal forall A B P H a, P a (fooify A B P H a).
Proof.
  intros A B P H a.
  unfold fooify.
  destruct constructive_indefinite_description as [b Pab].
  exact Pab.
Qed.
```

You can confirm the usage of the axiom using `Print Assumptions fooify.`